# Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 doesn't detect all my RAM

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, laptop, ram

I have one ChannelA-DIMM0 Micron 4 GB RAM Stick on my notebook. The bios and Windows 10 correctly identifies my ram as being 4096 MB, however Ubuntu only detects 3.7 GB. What could possibly be the issue?

```
free -m
```

:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available


Mem:      3726        1181         453         483        2091        1818

Swap:     3139           0        3139
```

- 

```
sudo lshw -c memory
```

:

```
  *-firmware                
   description: BIOS
   vendor: LENOVO
   physical id: 0
   version: KKCN10WW
   date: 04/14/2022
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 3MiB
   capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot


*-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 96KiB
       capacity: 96KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 23
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank
          description: Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 8 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

- 

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

:

```
KKCN10WW
```

Comment: Windows tells you what is installed. `free -m` tells you what can be used. Your notebook is dedicating 256MB of your RAM to the integrated video card, hence the 3.7GB value in `free`. Your `lshw` confirms that the stick is indeed 4GB.

Comment: @matigo I haven't even thought that this may be dedicated RAM for something else. Still 0,3 GB seems to be a lot, but well...
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @guiverc this is true for ordinary disk drives but not true for memory modules like RAM modules.